# Angular: Dom added ng-click return wrong this

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two functions:

```
$scope.modif = function (e) {
        $scope.temp = e.target.offsetParent
                              .offsetParent
                              .childNodes[3]
                              .childNodes[(this.$index+1)*2];
        $($scope.temp.childNodes[11])
         .html($compile('<button ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>')($scope));
};
```

// Generate a button in a ng-repeat context

and this (ng-click handler is genereted by the $scope.modif() function:

```
$scope.save = function (e) {
       console.log(this);
};
```

And the this is a global ng-repeat this, not in the specific ng-repeat clicked element.
However, the save button is next the modif button.

Someone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

The error was to put $scope in the $compile scope.
I reference this like new scope and it's work fine.

```
$($scope.temp.childNodes[11]).html($compile('<button ng-click="save($event)">Save</button>')(this));
```